# Is there a Google Chrome switch (command line) to toggle url-encoding?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, encoding, command-line-arguments

I have written a C# code that calls Google Chrome to load a specific url on the computers local hard drive. The C# code already encodes the URL (replaces  space characters with %20) and this used to work fine until a couple of weeks ago that [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084935/a-html-space-is-showing-as-2520-instead-of-20) started happening!

The quickest band-aid seems to be modifying the C# code to not replace " " with %20. But the Chrome behaviour may change in the future or some customers may not have the same verison of the chrome installed.

I think the sustainable solution is to Tell Chrome to either Encode or not encode the URL. Now my question is:

**Is there a Chrome switch that enforces it to either translate the url or ignore it?**

Does it have a setting or option for this?

I have found a couple of lists with Chrome Switches [Here](http://www.ericdlarson.com/misc/chrome_command_line_flags.html)  and [Here](http://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/06/list-useful-google-chrome-command-line-switches/). However both of these lists are incomplete and refer to [this reference](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) which seems to be not working!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the EXACT address you pass to chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is the (lack of) protocol in the address you pass to Chrome.

I am assuming you are passing a local file path such as `C:\mypath\something%20here.html`.

Chrome is (correctly!) asserting this is a local path and escaping characters that should be protected in a URL ( since `%` is a valid character for filenames ).

The *proper* way would be to either:

- give Chrome a normal file path with spaces and let it encode what needs encoding
- give a proper URL, where everything should already be encoded - the protocol for local URLs is `file://`

Thus, in the case of `C:\my path\my file.html` both of these should work:

- `C:\my path\my file.html`
- `file:///C:/my%20path/my%20file.html`
- `file://c:\my%20path\my%20file.html` (will be converted to the above by Chrome)

Comment: I just looked at my code and your assumption seems to be correct!

Comment: Thanks I could not replicate it on my dev machine cause the path did not have any spaces in it. so I moved everything to another folder and after running a test, your solution of adding file:// fixed my issue!

Comment: But I still dont know why it was not happening until a few weeks ago

Comment: Oh man, thank you. file:// really fixed the issue.